# Memory needed for computational graph

Tags: algorithm-analysis, space-analysis, data-flow-analysis, static-analysis

Suppose we have a set of equations like this

```
p7=f(p1+p6); p6=f(p2+p5); p5=f(p3+p4); p4=f(p3); p3=f(p2); p2=f(p1); p1=f()
```

It can be represented by computational graph below

[image]

If each intermediate value takes 1 unit of memory, you need at least 4 units to compute p7 without any duplicate computation.

Is there an algorithm for estimating memory needed in this setting for a general DAG?

I found a [paper](http://www.autodiff.org/ad04/abstracts/Hascoet.pdf) called "Adjoint Dataflow Analysis" for estimating this for restricted set of graphs, but it feels like this ought to be a problem that is covered more generally in graph theory.

Comment: Do you mean memory for storing the graph, or how much memory the represented computation needs?

Comment: I haven't thought about this very hard, but it may be an application of Dilworth's theorem. There's also a lot of literature on register allocation from DAG representations that is worth checking out. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth's_theorem

Comment: @Raphael -- need to know how much intermediate memory you need to compute p7

Answer (score 4):

Your problem sounds similar to one-shot (black) pebbling. [Wu, Austrin, Pitassi, and Liu](https://www.jair.org/media/4030/live-4030-7803-jair.pdf), in their paper titled *Inapproximability of treewidth, one-shot pebbling, and related layout problems* (J. Artificial Intelligence Res. 49 (2014), 569–600), show that it is (probably) hard to compute the optimal cost (which corresponds to your memory).

Comment: Thanks! I followed background link to find "Complete Register Allocation Problems", which shows how "pebbling" maps to memory allocation

Comment: BTW, this answer led to the memory saving package being implemented in TensorFlow, thanks! :) https://medium.com/tensorflow/fitting-larger-networks-into-memory-583e3c758ff9